# Is it possible to allow a user to send Test sends but not Live sends?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, content-builder

Is it possible to allow a content creator permissions to perform test sends but not send live sends?

If so what permissions would I need to select?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

Email > Content > Email > Test Send & Send

Grant **Test Send**, without granting **Send**.

[image]

You will also find **Advanced Test Send Options** in Email:

[image]

And under Interactions > Messages > Email:

[image]

How you configure it, depends on what the user should be allowed to test and how.